# How can I get the id from an async thunk function to extra reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reduce, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

// Delete thunk

```
export const deletePost = createAsyncThunk("deletePost", async (action) => {
  console.log(" ~ deletePost ~ action", action) // here I'm 
  getting id
  const response = await deletePos(action);
  return response.data;
});
```

I'm dispatching `id` to delete specific post from the posts array. The issue is cannot get the `id` from async thunk to extra reducer. I want the `id` in extra reducer fulfilled case so I can delete the specific post from the array. Is there a way to pass action from async thunk to extra reducer?

In action I'm getting the successful message from api, but I need the `id`

Extra reducer

```
builder.addCase(deletePost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  console.log(action)
  state.posts = state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
  state.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: What is `response.data`? *This* is what would be returned in the fulfilled action. Should you instead be replacing the state with the response value instead of trying to filter the current state, or returning a different action payload from the `deletePost` action?

Comment: @DrewReese In response.data i'm getting successfully deleted message

Comment: I need the same id in extra reducers which is passed to the api

Comment: Do you mean the deleted message (by id) is what is returned, not the full data minus that message? Have you tried `return action` (*assuming `action` is the id value you are referring to*)?

Comment: @DrewReese it works by returning the action from async thunk. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you should return the `action` value from the `deletePost` action. I'd suggest also renaming the parameter so it's clear to future readers *what* exactly that value represents.

Example:

```
export const deletePost = createAsyncThunk("deletePost", async (id) => {
  console.log(" ~ deletePost ~ id", { id });
  await deletePos(id);
  return id; // <-- return id value
});
```

```
builder.addCase(deletePost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.posts = state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
  state.loading = false;
});
```